# Angular unit testing the localstorage, Error ts(7053)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

beforeEach (() => { ...

```
   let store = {};
  const mockSessionStorage = {
  getItem: (key: string): string => key in store ? store[key] : null,
  setItem: (key: string, value: string) => store[key] = `${value}`,
  removeItem: (key: string) => delete store[key],
  clear: () => store = {}
};
...
```

and i get the Error Message The element implicitly has a type "any" because the expression of type "string" cannot be used for the index type "{}".
No index signature with a parameter of type "string" was found for type "{}".ts(7053)

Also I'm new to typscript and don't know if it's because of the error message or if I'm doing something else wrong I would be happy if someone could take a quick look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing your *store* variable.

Something like this:

```
let store:{ [key: string]: string } = {};
```

Comment: If I let store:{ [key: string]: string } = {}; so I get at getItem the message that the type string | null cannot be assigned to the type string ts(2322). To fix this I changed from type string to any. So let store:{ [key: string]: any} = {};. The error message is gone now but is my solution approach correct at all?

Comment: I guess your solution is OK, but first try with this change: let store:{ [key: string]: string|null} = {};